# Hardlink count inconsistent with matching files

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, hard-link

On searching for files that have hardlinks on my Portable HDD using the following command:

```
$ find . ! -type d -links +1 -ls | sort -n
```

I get an output of the following form (there are hundreds of other files)

```
9336 244476 -rw-------   2 rishi    rishi    250342060 Feb 18 15:48 ./unigram_mvt_0.001_9_4_0.001
```

This shows that the file with inode 9336 has 2 hardlinks.

On trying to locate the other one using

```
$ find /media/rishi/ -xdev -inum 9336
```

I get the output shown below

```
/media/rishi/mvp/unigram_mvt_0.001_9_4_0.001
```

This indicates that there is only file with inode 9336

I have not created hardlinks myself. These files have been generated on my local disk from a simulation on my computer. I might have copied files for taking backups which could have created these links. The files are currently on my Portable HDD

Since I do not need this data in the near future, I was using gzip to compress it when I came across the hardlinks warning and tried to look into it.

Is the hardlink count incorrect or am I not able to locate the other hard linked file?

EDIT:

Filesystem is fuseblk

Things tried:

1. Used sudo to search. Result: Same as before
2. Compressed file using "gzip -f". Result: Free space on the disk increased so I guess there were no other files hardlinked
3. Used find -name to check if it throws Hardlink count is wrong
   Warning. Result: No warning
4. Checked file system. I think the problem lies here but I'm not able to resolve it

Here is the output of disk check:

```
$ sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb1
Unsupported: replay_log()
Unsupported: check_volume()
Checking 199424 MFT records.
Unsupported cases found.

$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

Even after running `ntfsfix`, I get the same error on `ntfsck`

Comment: Did you try it with sudo?

Comment: What filesystem do you have on the external disk? Is it NTFS?

Comment: @xiadongjie Added details in the edit section

Comment: @terdon Yes, it is NTFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the filesystem. Thanks @terdon for the hint.

Apparently NTFS support on Linux is limited as the errors remain even after running ntfsfix.

Running `chkdsk /F /R /X F:` where F: is the drive letter from the elevated CMD prompt corrected the index entries and fixed the issue for me.